# Table Simplex method: 1) why do we need to have identity matrix? 2) Nonexistance of optimal solution 3) Stop iteration condition

Tags: math, methods, simplex

Recently I have read this superb Simplex method tutorial: http://www.tutor.ms.unimelb.edu.au/simplex_intro/index.html . While explaning things in very clear fashion, some obscurity still left.

1. From [here](http://www.tutor.ms.unimelb.edu.au/simplex_intro/gaussian.html) you may read (identity matrix):
   [image]
   So, what is the reason our table should have identity matrix in it? What if it does not have identity matrix?
2. From [here](http://www.tutor.ms.unimelb.edu.au/simplex_intro/non_negativity.html) (non-negativity):
   [image]
   Once again, please explain *why* this is so, don't simply tel that it *is* so, explain it.
3. From [here](http://www.tutor.ms.unimelb.edu.au/simplex_intro/objective.html) (stop iterations condition):
   [image]

Guarantee is very good, but I don't believe, please explain it! Also it would be very cool if your explanations be clear and logical - prove the concepts, use as much math as required, but make it clear and easy to understand, similarly as in the article! Thanks!

Comment: This question is probably better asked on [math.se]

Comment: @AakashM : probably so! Thanks for the link, will ask there.